# Translation of empty array element in XML to JSON became null in Oracle Service Bus Pipeline

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, osb

I'm facing an issue when working with Oracle Service Bus. I want to translate XML to JSON as the response but when using nxsd in OSB pipeline to do that translation the empty array (`<in:<ARRAYNAME>/>`) in XML will be translated as `"<ARRAYNAME>":[ null ]`. The expected result is `"<ARRAYNAME>":[]`, without null.

Here is the current response:

```
{
"data":     [ null ],
"description":      "Success",
"transactionId":    null,
"status":   0
}
```

Here is the expected response:

```
{
"data":     [ ] ,
"description":      "Success",
"transactionId":    null    ,
"status":   0
}
```